# Is there a way to display the original content of a twig template once it is loaded, before rendering anything?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Does someone know if there is a way to display the original raw content of a twig template once it is loaded, before rendering anything ?

Let's say that I've got a root template:

```
{# templates/template.txt.twig #}
This is my root template
{{arg1}}
{{ include('other/internal.txt.twig') }}
```

and another one included from the root one:

```
{# templates/other/internal.txt.twig #}
This is my included template
{{arg2}}
```

If I render `template.txt.twig` with arg1='foo' and arg2='bar', the result will be

```
This is my root template
foo
This is my included template
bar
```

It there a way to retrieve the loaded template before any variable evaluation ?
What I expect is to get something like this:

```
This is my root template
{{arg1}}
This is my included template
{{arg2}}
```

The idea behind that is to leverage all twig loading mechanism (loading path, namespaces...)
because I need to make some custom automatic checks on the twig code itself (not related to twig syntax but with the consistency of a high level model not related to twig)

Let me know if this makes sense or if you need more information
Thank you for your help

Comment: echo (file_get_contents ("/path/to/template/file.tpl"));

Comment: Are you wanting the `{{ arg1 }}` to stay as a string or be a string/parsed depending?

Comment: @GordonM thank you but as mentionned I want to benefit from Twig loading mechanisms during include that can be made between templates

Comment: @Qoop I really want {{arg1}} to stay as a string

Comment: If you are never wanting it to be parsed then you could just write it as a string like `{{ '{{ arg1 }}' }}` alternatively if you occasionally you wanted to use it as a variable or a string depending on if the variable was passed you could use `{{ arg1 is defined ? arg1 : '{{ arg1 }}' }}`.

Comment: Going from your question though (which I've now properly read) it looks like you want the template to be parsed but for you to be able to see the code before the template is parsed.. and then parse it after checks. Is that correct?

Comment: @Qoop Sorry, I wasn't clear. These templates primary use is to be evaluated by Twig, but I have another part of my program (a checker) which reads them without evaluation.

Based on the answers below, it seems that it is not possible due to theTwig template loading mechanism. Thank you for your help anyway

Comment: @Qoop Indeed yes that's what I want. Except that some times I render the template normally, and sometimes I want to be able to see the code before parsing

Comment: Are you wanting to output the unparsed template to the user or are you wanting to check it with some kind of service before it gets parsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a template, Twig compiles the Twig content into PHP code so I don't think this is possible with Twig itself. You can have a look at [the doc](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/5fd428ed7603ea63998716995c123c99648aab26/doc/internals.rst) or at [the presentation of Matthias Noback](http://fr.slideshare.net/matthiasnoback/diving-deep-into-twig) that Thierry gave you the link.

The only solution I think you have is to read the file with `file_get_contents` but you won't have the included template in the right place as in your exemple.

Comment: Thank you, so you're saying that the includes are not resolved before compilation into PHP code, but rather at the same time ? If it's the case, it seems that I will have to resolve the includes by hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to process the template with some kind of service before rendering it then you could override the twig environment and run your checks in the `loadTemplate` method.

For example here I will inject a `templateValidator` and then run that on each template load.

<kbd>App\AcmeBundle\Twig\Twig_Environment</kbd>

First extend `\Twig_Environment` and override the `loadTemplate` method as well as add a setter for injecting the `templateValidator`.

In the `loadTemplate` I have replaced instances of `$this->getLoader()->getSource($name)` with `$this->validateTemplate($name)` which does the same thing but also before what ever action you wish to add (in this case `$this->templateValidator->validate($source)`.

```
namespace App\AcmeBundle\Twig;

use \Twig_Environment as BaseEnvironment;

class Twig_Environment extends BaseEnvironment
{
    protected $templateValidator;

    public function setTemplateValidator(TemplateValidator $templateValidator)
    {
        $this->templateValidator = $templateValidator;
    }

    public function loadTemplate($name, $index = null)
    {
        $cls = $this->getTemplateClass($name, $index);

        if (isset($this->loadedTemplates[$cls])) {
            return $this->loadedTemplates[$cls];
        }

        if (!class_exists($cls, false)) {
            if (false === $cache = $this->getCacheFilename($name)) {
                //eval('?>'.$this->compileSource($this->getLoader()->getSource($name), $name));
                eval('?>'.$this->compileSource($this->validateTemplate($name), $name));
            } else {
                if (!is_file($cache) || ($this->isAutoReload() && !$this->isTemplateFresh($name, filemtime($cache)))) {
                    //$this->writeCacheFile($cache, $this->compileSource($this->getLoader()->getSource($name), $name));
                    $this->writeCacheFile($cache, $this->compileSource($this->validateTemplate($name), $name));
                }

                require_once $cache;
            }
        }

        if (!$this->runtimeInitialized) {
            $this->initRuntime();
        }

        return $this->loadedTemplates[$cls] = new $cls($this);
    }

    /**
     * Validate template and return source
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return string
     */
    private function validateTemplate($name)
    {
        $source = $this->getLoader()->getSource($name);

        if (null !== $this->templateValidator) {
            $this->templateValidator->validate($source);
        }

        return $source;
    }
}
```

<kbd>app/config/config.yml</kbd>

Override the parameter `twig.class` so DI uses your class rather than the original `\Twig_Environment`.

```
parameters:
    twig.class: App\AcmeBundle\Twig\Twig_Environment
```

<kbd>App\AcmeBundle\DependencyInject\Compiler\TwigEnvironmentInjectCompilerPass</kbd>

Create a compiler class to inject the `templateValidator` into your newly created `TwigEnvironment` (only if it has the `'setTemplateValidator'` method so it degrades properly)

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class TwigEnvironmentInjectCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('twig') || 
                !$container->hasDefinition('acme.template_validator'))
        {
            return;
        }

        $twig = $container->getDefinition('twig');

        if (!$twig->hasMethodCall('setTemplateValidator')) {
            return;
        }

        $twig->addMethodCall(
            'setTemplateValidator',
            array(new Reference('acme.template_validator'))
        );
    }
}
```

<kbd>App\AcmeBundle\AppAcmeBundle</kbd>

Add your compiler pass to the bundle build

```
use App\AcmeBundle\DependencyInject\Compiler\TwigEnvironmentInjectCompilerPass;

class AppAcmeBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new TwigEnvironmentInjectCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

**Note** This isn't tested in any way, it's all just off the top of my head, so it could all be wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have a look at it and let you know if I get to something.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Elao/WebProfilerExtraBundle` available at :

https://github.com/Elao/WebProfilerExtraBundle

might provide you with the additional details you're seeking in the aforementioned example.

See also:

http://qpleple.com/webprofilerbundleextra-a-must-have-tool-for-symfony2-developers/
http://www.slideshare.net/matthiasnoback/diving-deep-into-twig

Comment: Thank you ! I will have a look at it and let you know if it suits my needs.

Comment: From what I read from the "diving deep into twig" presentation, the way Twig works does not allow me to do what I want